# GLSL, how are interpolateAtSample/Offset supposed to work?

Tags: opengl, glsl, interpolation, offset, multisampling

I have this question now since a long time, I can't get a simple multisample example running..

[This](https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples/blob/master/tests/gl-400-fbo-multisample.cpp) is the original code, [this](https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples/blob/master/data/gl-400/multisample.vert) is the vs and [this](https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples/blob/master/data/gl-400/multisample.frag) the fs, that I report here for convenience:

```
layout(location = POSITION) in vec2 Position;
layout(location = TEXCOORD) in vec2 Texcoord;

out vert
{
    vec2 Texcoord;
} Vert;

void main()
{   
    Vert.Texcoord = Texcoord;
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(Position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

---

```
in vert
{
    vec2 Texcoord;
} Vert;

layout(location = FRAG_COLOR, index = 0) out vec4 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = texture(Diffuse, interpolateAtSample(Vert.Texcoord, gl_SampleID));
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> Shader status invalid: 0(20) : error C5229: Argument 1 for
>   interpolateAtSample must have no component selection

What? I understand the [specs](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/gpu_shader5.txt) says:

> ```
> Built-in interpolation functions are available to compute an
> interpolated
> value of a fragment shader input variable at a shader-specified (x,y)
> location.  A separate (x,y) location may be used for each invocation of
> the built-in function, and those locations may differ from the default
> (x,y) location used to produce the default value of the input.
>
>   float interpolateAtCentroid(float interpolant);
>   vec2 interpolateAtCentroid(vec2 interpolant);
>   vec3 interpolateAtCentroid(vec3 interpolant);
>   vec4 interpolateAtCentroid(vec4 interpolant);
>
>   float interpolateAtSample(float interpolant, int sample);
>   vec2 interpolateAtSample(vec2 interpolant, int sample);
>   vec3 interpolateAtSample(vec3 interpolant, int sample);
>   vec4 interpolateAtSample(vec4 interpolant, int sample);
>
>   float interpolateAtOffset(float interpolant, vec2 offset);
>   vec2 interpolateAtOffset(vec2 interpolant, vec2 offset);
>   vec3 interpolateAtOffset(vec3 interpolant, vec2 offset);
>   vec4 interpolateAtOffset(vec4 interpolant, vec2 offset);
>
> The function interpolateAtCentroid() will return the value of the input
> varying <interpolant> sampled at a location inside the both the pixel and
> the primitive being processed.  The value obtained would be the same value
> assigned to the input variable if declared with the "centroid" qualifier.
>
> The function interpolateAtSample() will return the value of the input
> varying <interpolant> at the location of the sample numbered <sample>.  If
> multisample buffers are not available, the input varying will be evaluated
> at the center of the pixel.  If the sample number given by <sample> does
> not exist, the position used to interpolate the input varying is
> undefined.
>
> The function interpolateAtOffset() will return the value of the input
> varying <interpolant> sampled at an offset from the center of the pixel
> specified by <offset>.  The two floating-point components of <offset>
> give the offset in pixels in the x and y directions, respectively.  
> An offset of (0,0) identifies the center of the pixel.  The range and
> granularity of offsets supported by this function is
> implementation-dependent.  
>
> For all of the interpolation functions, <interpolant> must be an input
> variable or an element of an input variable declared as an array.
> Component selection operators (e.g., ".xy") may not be used when
> specifying <interpolant>.  If <interpolant> is declared with a "flat" or
> "centroid" qualifier, the qualifier will have no effect on the
> interpolated value.  If <interpolant> is declared with the "noperspective"
> qualifier, the interpolated value will be computed without perspective
> correction.
> ```

But I still don't get why. The interpolant has no component selection and it is an input variable coming from a bound vertex attribute in the vs.
Or does it interpret the `.Texcoord` of `Vert.Texcoord` has component selection operator?

I get also the same error in another sample, however, on `interpolateAtOffset`.

What is wrong? I mean, I want to interpolate the `gl_SampleID` at the given offset, I don't know how else shall that function be used..

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. The specification clearly says, "Component selection operators (e.g., .xy) may be used when specifying
interpolant." Odds are good that the compiler is getting confused, since you're accessing a member of an interface block.

Comment: I was suggested the same on the opengl irc channel, but I didn't have much lucky on the [nvidia forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/914874/opengl/glsl-compiler-bug-on-interpolateatsample-/?offset=6#4813072)